# How to separate Roman numerals for a range of numbers?

Tags: typography, roman-numerals

Arabic numerals are separated using en-dash:

```
pages 101--123, 2--3 and so on
```

What is typographically correct way to separate **Roman** numerals?

For example:

with en-dash

```
in the XIX--XX centuries
```

with en-dash plus two `\,`

```
in the XIX\,--\,XX centuries
```

or, maybe, with the usual dash

```
in the XIX\,---\,XX centuries
```

Comment: I'd say that you should use (i) en-dashes and (ii) whatever amount of horizontal separation between the (roman) numerals and en-dashes that's appropriate for your country's typographic practice. In the U.S., it's not customary to insert a space (generally a thin-space) between the numerals and the dash, but in some other countries it *is* customary to do so.

Comment: Conceptually, an en-dash is used where 'and' or 'to' is appropriate (at least in the tradition in the UK). Thus a page range with any form of page numbering is an en-dash, as you would read as 'to'.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

for a page span, an en-dash (`iv--ix`) would be appropriate.  i see no reason why this shouldn't also be appropriate for cap roman numerals for centuries.  the en-dash, with no surrounding spaces, traditionally indicates a span in u.s. typography.  as mico points out in a comment, the typographic traditions regarding spaces may differ in other countries.